# Color depending on section number

Tags: color

I'm working on a document which is divided into chapters. Each chapter is divided into 4 sections. I would like to create a command that defines a color depending on the number of the section.

I've been trying to do so using `ifthen` package :

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
...
\newcommand{\myColor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\thesection = 1}{DarkOrange}{%
        \ifthenelse{\thesection = 2}{DeepSkyBlue}{%
            \ifthenelse{\thesection = 3}{MediumSeaGreen}{%
            DimGray}%
        }%
    }%
}%
```

I use `titlesec` to customize my section titles.

I get the following error :

```
Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition \section{exploration}
```

pointing to the line of my first section.

How could I correct this ?

Comment: Are you trying to  colour the section headings, or make the colour available within the section?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you have in your preamble something like `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code can't work, because the argument of `\color` must be expandable, which `\ifthenelse` isn't.

Define four colors with a suffix dependent on the section number:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
 {\Large\bfseries\color{sectioncolor\arabic{section}}}
 {\thesection}
 {1em}
 {}

\colorlet{sectioncolor1}{DarkOrange}
\colorlet{sectioncolor2}{DeepSkyBlue}
\colorlet{sectioncolor3}{MediumSeaGreen}
\colorlet{sectioncolor4}{DimGray}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{First is DarkOrange}

\section{Second is DeepSkyBlue}

\section{Third is MediumSeaGreen}

\section{Fourth is DimGray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not providing a minimal working example (a complete LaTeX program that is very short yet illustrates the problem you're having) I don't know what your intentions are.  But the following works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myColor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\thesection = 1}{\color{DarkOrange}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\thesection = 2}{\color{DeepSkyBlue}}{%
            \ifthenelse{\thesection = 3}{\color{MediumSeaGreen}}{%
            \color{DimGray}}%
        }%
    }%
}%

%\def\couleur\expandafter\color{\myColor}

\begin{document}

{\myColor section 0}

\section{hello}

{\myColor
\lipsum[1-2]}

\section{howdy}

{\myColor \lipsum[3-4]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works well.
But if I define a function using myColor :
    \newcommand{\myFunction}[1]{%
    {\bfseries{\myColor}  #1}}
and if I call the function in differents sections, the color used is always the same

Comment: Remove the curly brackets around \myColor.  They limit the scope of your command.

Comment: Thank for your code. But how can we refresh color of each section by chapter?