# Add Chapter Thumb to pages

Tags: chapterthumb

This question is building from the solution code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328323/fancy-headers-on-even-and-odd-pages).  I wanted to know how to add the chapter thumb like this:

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}
\definecolor{fillh}{RGB}{225,233,251}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER THUMB
%======================================================================================
\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}


\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  %\ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}
  ultramarine}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[E]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south east) {\thechapter};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (chapter.south east) {\leftmark};
    \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\fancyhead[O]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south west) {\thechapter};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east] at (chapter.south west) {\leftmark};
      \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Problems}
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\cleardoublepage

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix \thechapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions about chapter thumbs etc. on the site. Have you looked at the solutions provided in those?

Comment: Did you try the [thumbs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding just 5 lines (marked with `%%%% <--- !`) to your code adds thumb marks to the output. For the width/height of the marks, text size in the marks etc. you need to set some options of the [thumbs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs). Please have a look at its manual and example file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{atveryend}%%%% <--- !
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}
\definecolor{fillh}{RGB}{225,233,251}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER THUMB
%======================================================================================
\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}


\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  %\ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}
  ultramarine}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[E]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south east) {\thechapter};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (chapter.south east) {\leftmark};
    \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\fancyhead[O]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south west) {\thechapter};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east] at (chapter.south west) {\leftmark};
      \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}


\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={2mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}%%%% <--- !


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}%%%% <--- !
\chapter{Problems}
\addthumb{\thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{mybluei}%%%% <--- !
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\cleardoublepage

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix \thechapter}
\addthumb{\thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{mybluei}%%%% <--- !
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```