# Write the number of pages at the right/left of each page

Tags: page-numbering, customize

I want to insert the page number as seen here:

[image]

that changes in accordance with the chapter (the pages of the chapter have all page numbers inserted in the same position, whereas for the subsequent chapter, they are inserted a bit below the first position). I don't know if I am clear enough.

Comment: There are a couple of package for a thumb index on ctan, maybe have a look if these can help

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328430/add-chapter-thumb-to-pages?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C49.2631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example using KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[automark,pagestyleset=KOMA-Script,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newlength{\outermarkoffset}
\setlength{\outermarkoffset}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  oddpage,
  outermargin,
  addvoffset=\dimexpr \outermarkoffset+\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax,
  contents={%
    \raggedleft\pagemark\hspace*{1em}\par
  },
]{oddpagenumber}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  evenpage,
  outermargin,
  addvoffset=\dimexpr \outermarkoffset+\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax,
  contents={%
    \raggedright\hspace*{1em}\pagemark\par
  },
]{evenpagenumber}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{oddpagenumber,evenpagenumber}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{oddpagenumber,evenpagenumber}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtolength{\outermarkoffset}{\dimexpr\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you are already using package `fancyhdr`, you can use `scrlayer-fancyhdr` instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scrlayer-fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\pagemark}%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\newlength{\outermarkoffset}
\setlength{\outermarkoffset}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  oddpage,
  outermargin,
  addvoffset=\dimexpr \outermarkoffset+\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax,
  contents={%
    \raggedleft\pagemark\hspace*{1em}\par
  },
]{oddpagenumber}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
  background,
  evenpage,
  outermargin,
  addvoffset=\dimexpr \outermarkoffset+\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax,
  contents={%
    \raggedright\hspace*{1em}\pagemark\par
  },
]{evenpagenumber}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{oddpagenumber,evenpagenumber}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtolength{\outermarkoffset}{\dimexpr\baselineskip*\value{chapter}*2\relax}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of different chapters]

For more information about [`scrlayer-fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-fancyhdr) see the manual of that package.

For more information about `\DeclareNewLayer` and `\AddLayersToPageStyle` see the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manuals.

For more information about `\AddToHook` see `lthooks-doc.pdf`, which is part of every LaTeX distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however when using the second proposed script I get to page numbering. I only want one and I want it in a drawn space (will eventually want it to be colored in black and the number in white)

Comment: @Wallflower Your example image also has two page numbers (one in the outer margin and one in the footline). However, you can easily remove the number in the footer, e.g., using `\fancyfoot[C]{}`. Color was also not part of the question, but is simple using package `xcolor` and e.g., `\colorbox` and `\color`. Please ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I cannot use the \fancyfoot command since I am using the MastersDoctoralThesis template for my report :(

Comment: @Wallflower How should I know this from your image and insufficient description in your question? This is why you should always add a minimal working example to your questions. But AFAIK `MasterDoctoralThesis` already uses `scrlayer-scrpage`. So you can use all the nice macros of that package to add an remove fields, e.g., `\cfoot[]{}`. Please read the manual.

Comment: I posted a new question as previously requested here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683772/creative-page-numbering-without-using-fancyhdr?noredirect=1#comment1696540_683772. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: @Wallflower Questions should basically stand for themselves. Helpers cannot be expected to go through all of a questioner's questions and check them for relevance. Questions that stand for themselves are also beneficial for other help seekers.

Comment: Understood, thank you!