# Creative page numbering without using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, layout

I need help with the page numbering of my report.

I am willing to change my page numbering and make it look like this.[image]

with the placement of the page numbering to change with the chapter (the higher the chapter number the lower the placement).

PS: I am using MastersDoctoralThesis so I cannot use fancyhdr...

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[
10=2pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,fit,matrix,shapes,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,calligraphy,shadows}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{khrawi2}{RGB}{220,200,90}
\definecolor{khrawi}{RGB}{85,34,0}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255,255,0}
\definecolor{noir}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{200,51,51}
\definecolor{mapink}{RGB}{255,169,169}
\definecolor{mablue}{RGB}{33,190,208}
\definecolor{hotpink}{RGB}{255,105,180}
\colorlet{linkequation}{darkgreen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
\newsavebox\MBox
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}

\newcommand\Cline[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}%
        \rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-3\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{1pt}}}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks,linktoc=all,linkcolor=gray,urlcolor=black,pdfencoding=auto,psdextra,citecolor=blue,menucolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\glsplainhyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup%
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
    \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}
\let\@glslink\glsplainhyperlink
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\figref}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=red,
        linkbordercolor=red,
    }%
    \ref{#1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\myrefeq}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=linkequation,
        linkbordercolor=linkequation,
    }%
    \eqref{#1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=khrawi,
        linkbordercolor=khrawi,
    }%
    \ref{#1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\tabref}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=hotpink,
        linkbordercolor=hotpink,
    }%
    \ref{#1}%
    \endgroup
}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    %   papersize={176mm,256mm}
    paper=b5paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    left=15mm, 
    right=15mm,
    top =6mm,
    bottom=6mm,
    layouthoffset=3mm,
    layoutvoffset=3mm
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Title here} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
%\supervisor{
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{\LARGE\textsc{Degree}} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{ME} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{EE} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{University} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{b} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{n} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
    \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% Creating the glossary
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{Glossaries/glossaries.tex}

\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
\setlist{nosep,leftmargin=*}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
    \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

Faculty

\vspace{0.3cm}
\textsc{\Large \textbf{ Thesis}}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{\Large \textbf{degree}}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{in}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{\Large \textbf{ee}}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{Presented by}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{\Large\textbf{\authorname}}\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{Entitled}\\[0.3cm]

\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.3cm}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
\vspace{0.3cm}



\cleardoublepage

\dominitoc

{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
    \tableofcontents
    \adjustmtc
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
    \adjustmtc
    \newpage}

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{thesis}

\chapter{chapter1}
    \minitoc
    \section{1}
    \section{2}
    
\chapter{chapter2}
    \minitoc
    \section{1}
    \section{2}
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've never used the class, but AFAIK it uses `scrlayer-scrpage` for the page style. So you can use this package too. Try also a [search for “header-footer MastersDoctoralThesis”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bheader-footer%5D+MastersDoctoralThesis) for some already existing examples.

Comment: If you ever figure out how to set  the header, I suspect you can use `\rlap{\makebox[\myrightmargin][r]{...}}` where `\myrightmargin` has to be computed (`\dimexpr \paperwidth-\1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth` for example).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could, but `scrlayer-scrpage` also has an option, e.g., to span the header across the width of the whole page.