# Chapter name does not display

Tags: sectioning, chapters

This question is building off the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329264/modify-fancyheader-and-also-shift-main-body-text-down).  I wanted to remove "Chapter X" from the titles of the pages, however, with the code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}
```

all the Chapter headings disappear.  I would like to just display "Problem X" on the chapter headings.

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
      {\tikz[baseline=(a.base), overlay]{
            \node[fill=mybluei, anchor=south west, outer sep=0, draw=none, inner sep=.5mm,
                text=white,font=\Large, text width=1.5cm, align=center, minimum height=8.5mm,
                label={[text=myblueii]right:#1}
            ] (a) {\thesection};
        \foreach \x in {.25,.5,.75}{%
        \draw[mybluei, ultra thick] (a) ($(a.south west)!\x!(a.north west)$) --++ (-4,0);
        }
        \draw[myblueii, ultra thick] ($(a.south east)!.25!(a.north east)$) --++ (\textwidth-1.6cm,0);
        }
      }
      {1em}
      {}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}

\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1-5]

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the chapter and section numbers in the headers and footers insert

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

after `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you load `titlesec` with option `explicit`, you have to use the parameter `#1` for the chapter title. Also describe the formatting and spacing of `chapter` and  `\section` only once. Last observation: you don't have to patch `\chapter` to get fancy page style on the first page of chapters: it can be incorporated in `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
      {\tikz[baseline=(a.base), overlay]{
            \node[fill=mybluei, anchor=south west, outer sep=0, draw=none, inner sep=.5mm,
                text=white,font=\Large, text width=1.5cm, align=center, minimum height=8.5mm,
                label={[text=myblueii]right:#1}
            ] (a) {\thesection};
        \foreach \x in {.25,.5,.75}{%
        \draw[mybluei, ultra thick] (a) ($(a.south west)!\x!(a.north west)$) --++ (-4,0);
        }
        \draw[myblueii, ultra thick] ($(a.south east)!.25!(a.north east)$) --++ (\textwidth-1.6cm,0);
        }
      }
      {1em}
      {}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}[\leavevmode\thispagestyle{fancy}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}

\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1-5]

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get a bad box? There's one I couldn't get rid of. (Actually, I think I introduced it, though I got rid of the enormous number of bad boxes there were originally.) I think it is just because the dummy content leaves a too empty page, but I got frustrated pinpointing it and gave up. Maybe the section formatting eliminates it, though ...

Comment: @cfr: I had one bad vbox indeed (badness 1009). As you aroused my curiosity, I ended in solving the problem with geometry: I jusrreplaced `headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}` with  `headheight=120pt, top={\headheight+10mm}` and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity! I was frustrated because I managed to introduce it after eliminating every had hbox in the original.