# Change Color and Size of Chapter Name

Tags: formatting, color, chapters, fontsize, bold

This question is building of the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329288/chapter-name-does-not-display).  I am trying to change the color (to cyan) and size of the font (20pt and bold) of the chapter name.  I tried changing the line:

`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}[\leavevmode\thispagestyle{fancy}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}`

but this had no effect.

Can you please help me change the chapter name font?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\SectionFont\color{myblueii}}
      {\tikz[baseline=(a.base), overlay]{
            \node[fill=mybluei, anchor=south west, outer sep=0, draw=none, inner sep=.5mm,
                text=white,font=\Large, text width=1.5cm, align=center, minimum height=8.5mm,
                label={[text=myblueii]right:#1}
            ] (a) {\thesection};
        \foreach \x in {.25,.5,.75}{%
        \draw[mybluei, ultra thick] (a) ($(a.south west)!\x!(a.north west)$) --++ (-4,0);
        }
        \draw[myblueii, ultra thick] ($(a.south east)!.25!(a.north east)$) --++ (\textwidth-1.6cm,0);
        }
      }
      {1em}
      {}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge#1}[\leavevmode\thispagestyle{fancy}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}

\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1-5]

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under an `11pt` document class option in [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co), `\huge` is defined as

```
\newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
```

which sets the font size to `\@xxpt`, or `20.47pt`; see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Also, since you're using the `explicit` option with [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), placement of font and colour-related changes is best accompanied with the `#1` argument as part of `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\color{cyan}\huge\bfseries#1}[\leavevmode\thispagestyle{fancy}]
```

[image]

Comment: Specific font size changes are possible via `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont`, if needed (and supported by the font).