# Switch chapter header images

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

this code is building from the solution given [here where an image is added to the headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329264/modify-fancyheader-and-also-shift-main-body-text-down).  In the code from the [Legrande Orange Template given here,](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) the programmer uses a switch like `\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf}` to change the images that appear in the chapter headers.

Is there a similar approach that can be employed to switch the header chapter images using a similar "switching" approach to the code given below instead of re-typing and changing the `\fancyhead[O]` and `\fancyhead[E]` environments for each chapter?

Here is the original code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=120pt]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

%have a different header image here
\chapter{Problem 1}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

%have a different header image here - say like the "example-image-d" and "example-image-e" images
\chapter{Problem 2}

\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Still obsessed from Legrand Orange? ;-)

Comment: Guilty as charged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use macros or a boxes instead of `\includegraphics[…]{…}` in the definition of the odd and even page head. And you can define a command to change these macros or boxes. In the following example I use boxes, because setting up boxes once and using them multiple times is faster than expanding macros several times:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven
\newcommand*{\headimages}[3][]{%
  % #1 - optional argument added to the optional argument of both \includegraphics
  % #2 - name of even/left side page head image
  % #3 - name of odd/right side page head image
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\headimages{example-image-b}{example-image-a}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Problem 1}
\headimages{example-image-c}{example-image}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Solution 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Problem 2}
\headimages{example-image-a}{example-image-b}
\section{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Note: I cannot use `example-image-d`, because package `mwe` only provides `example-image-a` up to `example-image-c`. So I've used `example-image` instead of `example-image-c` and once again `example-image-a` and `example-image-c`. But I think you will understand how to use it with different images.