# Remove Section Number in Header or Footer

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering

The following code is based on: [Fancy header and footers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296509/fancy-header-and-footers)

I would like to remove the section number in the header but keep it in the main text. I have tried but without succes:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-1in)$);
    \node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\Large, minimum size=1in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\leftmark};
      %node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2cm, draw, rectangle, fill=blue!20, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {\Large\bfseries \quad #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{document}
%\chapter{first chapter}
\section{Sectiona A}
\lipsum[1-9]

%\chapter{second chapter}
\newpage
\section{Section B}
\lipsum[10-19]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as adding

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
```

to your preamble.

[image]

By default, `\sectionmark` - the macro responsible for setting the mark associated with `\section` - resembles this:

```
\newcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@
        \thesection
        \hskip 1em
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}
```

I've just removed the conditional setting of `\thesection` (and space).