# How to eliminate space between fancyhdr and top/sides of page

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I would like to have a solid rectangle (with some text inside it) as my heading.  I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{heading1}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=darkgray] (0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,2);
\node[white] at (2, 1) {Some heading text on page 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{heading1}

Some text on page 1

\end{document}
```

But the gray rectangle does not extend to the far left side of the page (although it does go to the far right side), nor does it extend to the top.

Comment: You need something like `\hspace*{\dimexpr -1in-\oddsidemargin}`.  You can also go with tikzpagenodes, everypage or `\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}...`

Comment: You can refer to a previous topic on this. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296509/fancy-header-and-footers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your rectangle from the top left corner. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{heading1}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=darkgray] (current page.north west) rectangle(\paperwidth,-1);
\node[white] at (2, 1) {Some heading text on page 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{heading1}
Some text on page 1
\end{document}
```

[image: Gray rectangle on top of page]

There is probably a more correct way to do a thing like this.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple rectangle, you do not need `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=4cm,headheight=3cm,headsep=1cm}
\fancypagestyle{heading1}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{\centering\makebox[0pt][c]{\colorbox{blue!60}{
\centering\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][c]{.99\paperwidth}
\hspace{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{white} Some heading text on page 1
\end{minipage}}}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{heading1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```